# Vim paragraph motions { } not performing as expected

Tags: vim

Whilst editing a text file I found that the `{` and `}` (paragraph back / paragraph forward) motions navigated to two points in the file which were not paragraph breaks.

The file in question is identified in Notepad++ as ANSI as UTF-8 and contains some cyrillic looking characters.

The file was generated by creating a backup of a filter subscription list setting in the AdblockPlus Firefox extension.

I don't understand why the motion operators would suddenly stop in the middle of a paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help paragraph`:

> A paragraph begins after each empty line, and also at each of a set of
>   paragraph macros, specified by the pairs of characters in the 'paragraphs'
>   option.  The default is "IPLPPPQPP TPHPLIPpLpItpplpipbp", which corresponds to
>   the macros ".IP", ".LP", etc.  (These are nroff macros, so the dot must be in
>   the first column).  A section boundary is also a paragraph boundary.
>
> A section begins after a form-feed (<C-L>) in the first column and at each of
>   a set of section macros, specified by the pairs of characters in the
>   'sections' option.  The default is "SHNHH HUnhsh", which defines a section to
>   start at the nroff macros ".SH", ".NH", ".H", ".HU", ".nh" and ".sh".

So, it could be some strange characters starting with `.` in column 1, or a form-feed (`^L`).

The first one can be avoided with `:set paragraphs= sections=`.

Also, check that you don't have a mapping overload of `}` via `:verbose nmap }`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. The two lines that { } were stopping at both began .sh.

Comment: Ah, great! This is one of the rare oddities that Vim inherited from its _vi_ heritage.